# $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{(x-y) \sin(xy)}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{(x-y)\sin(xy)}{x^2+y^2} \, dy \, dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Justify the following statement.

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{(x-y)\sin(xy)}{x^2+y^2} \, dx \, dy = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{(x-y)\sin(xy)}{x^2+y^2}\,dy\,dx.$$

What it means by justification here. I know we want to apply the Fubinis theorem here. Is it enough to show the conditions of fubinis theorem or should we evaluate the double integral separately.

Is it enough to show $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left|\frac{(x-y)\sin(xy)} {x^2+y^2}\right| \, dx \, dy<\infty$. Help on this is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you can show Fubini's theorem applies, then yes that should work for what they're asking

Comment: For what you're trying to prove, it is enough to show that $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left|\frac{(x-y)\sin(xy)} {x^2+y^2}\right| \, dx \, dy<\infty,$ since that is what Fubini's theorem says. But notice also how I cleaned up your MathJax code.

Answer (score 5):

Make use of the fact that $2|xy| \leq x^2+y^2$ to bound the integrand
$$
\left|
\frac{(x-y)\sin(xy}{x^2+y^2}
\right|
\leq
\frac{|(x-y)\sin(xy)|}{2|xy|},
$$
and notice that the resulting bound is continuous up to removable discontinuities at $xy=0$ (use the classical limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(h)/h = 1$), hence integrable.